# Colour points if they are in a character vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
fun <- data.frame(object = (c("banana", "pasta", "apple", "worm"), 
                  value1 = c(1,2,3,5), 
                  value2 = c(4,3,3,1))
```

Then I can plot value1 vs. value2 using ggplot

```
ggplot(fun, aes(y = value2, x = value1)) +
  geom_point()
```

But I also have a separate vector like this:

```
fruits <- c("lemon", "apple", "orange", "banana")
```

How can I use this vector to colour the plot dots according whether `fun$object` is in the `fruits` vector or not, so I can get a plot with fruit and non-fruit objects coloured differently?

I'm interested in a fairly efficient solution, as my data is quite large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fun <- data.frame(cbind(c("banana", "pasta", "apple", "worm"), 
                        c(1,2,3,5), c(4,3,3,1)))

colnames(fun) <- c("object", "value1", "value2")

fruits <- c("lemon", "apple", "orange", "banana")

fun$col <- fun$object %in% fruits

ggplot(fun, aes(y = value2, x = value1)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=col))
```